# Approach for Spring Cloud microservices with Consul on Docker Swarm 1.12++

Tags: java, docker, spring-cloud, docker-swarm, consul

I have several microservices on Spring Cloud ecosystem and as a config server and registration server I have Consul. Also I have Docker Swarm on 4 noded and 3 consul agents as server mode and 1 consul agent as client mode one for each node.

What is my problem: 
I try to run on each node on the instance of consul as a docker container, for example:

```
docker run -d --name consul -h node1 -p 8500:8500 -p ... progrium/consul -server -advertise ${CONSUL_MASTER} -bootstrap-expect 3
```

and join other consul agents to main consul:

```
docker run -d --name consul -h node2 -p 8500:8500 -p ... progrium/consul -server -advertise $(docker info --format "{{.Swarm.NodeAddr}}") -join ${CONSUL_MASTER}
```

and then deploy my microservices as a stack in Docker Swarm:

`docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml my_stek`

My bootstrap.yml in each microservice is:

`spring:
  application:
    name: service-name
  cloud:
    consul:
      host: consul
      port: 8500
      config:
        enabled: true
        format: yaml`

After I have a problem with discovery my services, because of network -
 Consul isn't run in swarm cluster and can't check health of my microservices and my microservices can't receive configuration file from config server.

So, please, help me to organize the right architecture. May be I should run my consul in Swarm cluster - is a normal way to solve this problem or it has other solutions. Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem ? I have a similar issue, but with eureka  and docker-compose https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45330035/spring-cloud-netflix-and-docker-compose-cannot-register-services-with-eureka

Comment: I've found one article with this problem: http://blog.wescale.fr/2017/01/04/tutoriel-infastructure-resiliente-et-scalable-avec-swarm-consul-et-traefik/
but I think it isn't completely correct approach. 

I decided to change Consul to Eureka and run all my services with Eureka in stack