# Spring Cloud Netflix and Docker Compose - cannot register services with eureka

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I'm trying to use docker-compose to run 2 simple services locally (Ubuntu): a eureka server, and config server (which is also a eureka client). Both of these have simple dockerfiles that run `java -jar`, expose their ports, and individually work fine. I also tried to add `eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://company-service-discovery:8761/eureka` to see if it would register itself, and it worked.

My config server cannot successfully register to the eureka server, and I've googled it and nothing I've seen helped me solve this.

According to docker-compose documentation at https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/ :

> By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each container for a service joins the default network and is both reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by them at a hostname identical to the container name.

With the following example `web` should be able to use `postgres://db:5432` to communicate with the database.

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "8001:5432"
```

I have used the same method to configure my services, but my config server gets connection refused when trying to register:

## docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  company-service-discovery:
    build: company-service-discovery/
    ports:
      - "8761:8761"
  company-config-server:
    build: company-config-server/
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    links:
      - company-service-discovery
```

## config server bootstrap.yml

```
server:
  port: 8888

management:
  security:
    enabled: false

spring:
  application:
    name: company-config-server
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        native:
          search-locations: classpath:/shared
  profiles:
    include: native

eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://company-service-discovery:8761/eureka
```

## eureka server bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: company-service-discovery

server:
  port: 8761

management:
  security:
    enabled: false
```

## exception

```
2017-07-26 14:25:05.738  WARN 1 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failed with message: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2017-07-26 14:25:05.739  WARN 1 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_COMPANY-CONFIG-SERVER/365d20275ab0:company-config-server:8888 - registration failed Cannot execute request on any known server
```

## question

Is there anything wrong with my configuration ? How can I make it work ?

Let me know if there's any info missing, I'll gladly give any info I can.

Answer (score 2):

Add the `defaultZone` configuration to the Eureka server's properties too (and change the `service-url` to `serviceUrl` in your ***config server bootstrap.yml***).

### eureka server bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: company-service-discovery

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://company-service-discovery:8761/eureka

server:
  port: 8761

management:
  security:
    enabled: false
```

Comment: I fought with this for several days until today I ended up re-creating the docker images after re-creating the jars with `mvn clean install`. I was stupid and forgot to do that after changing from `localhost` to the service name URL in the properties files. Everything ended up working after that. Not sure what to do about the question now. Should I edit the original post with the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you sooo much. this post resolved my problem - connecting eureka client to eureka server with docker. After 2 days of searching it work. I am in tears.

So basically -

you should use following in eureka client's application.properties/.yml

eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://eureka-server:8761/eureka

and in docker-compose.yml your eureka service name should match with - the url host name, in my case it is - eureka-server